# Calculate text height properly independently of font used to make a text element with a right arrow

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a label that has a right arrow. It looks like this:

[image: Arrow example]

The code I'm using is the following (LESS):

```
@font-size: 14px;
@padding-top: 4px;
@arrow-bheight: @font-size;

.label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: @font-size;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: @padding-top 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  
  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: @arrow-bheight solid transparent;
    border-bottom: @arrow-bheight solid transparent;
    border-left: @arrow-bheight solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: -@arrow-bheight;
    top:0;
  }
}
```

My problem is that depending on the font we use, **the arrow doesn't fit perfectly into the text font**.

[image: Problem of arrows not fitting into text]

I've been trying to set a specific value for the `line-height`, e.g. `line-height: @font-size`, but it's not working.

#### [Here's a CodePen of the problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uFcHx).

How can I make the right arrow have the proper height regardless of the font used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to define `@padding-top` variable separately. Instead you could use `em` unit which is relative to the element's `font-size`.

Also you should change the `display` type of the labels to `inline-block`:

**[Updated Example](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/rzwix)**

```css
.label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: @font-size; /* This has been set to 14px */
    padding: 0.5em 8px;    /* The computed value of 0.5em would be 14px/2 = 7px */
    line-height: 1;
    /* other declarations... omitted due to brevity */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that may help...

The [background-position edge offsets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-background-offsets) and the [CSS calc unit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

I'm not familiar with the first though CSS `calc` will let you do things such as...

```
height: calc(100% - 24px);
```